# Make timer along with music when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, audio, timer

I'd like to start a timer when this button is clicked. I've found a ton of timers that start when page loads. But none that start when a button is clicked. An additional complication is it needs to start simultaneously as the sound starts. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 <button class="button1" 
 onclick="document.getElementById('sound1').play()">   
 </button>
```

Comment: You want to start timer on button click ? What is sound ?

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript you can manipulate your `DOM` like this :

```js
//Pause audio on document load
document.getElementById('sound1').pause();
//Detect button clikc
document.getElementById('play').addEventListener("click", cuntingsec, false); 

//Function to count second 
function cuntingsec()
{
  var seconds = 0;
  var el = document.getElementById('seconds-counter');

  function incrementSeconds() {
      seconds += 1;
      el.innerText = "Audio is played " + seconds + " seconds.";
//Detect audio end
document.getElementById('sound1').addEventListener("ended", function(){
            el.innerText = "Audio is played " + seconds + " seconds. and ended";
      //Clear interval
      clearInterval(cancel);

});
  }

  var cancel = setInterval(incrementSeconds, 1000);
}
```

```html
<audio id="sound1" autostart="0" src="http://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/2926/=AudioTest_(1).ogg" autoplay>
  Votre navigateur ne supporte pas l'élément <code>audio</code>.
</audio>
<div id='seconds-counter'> </div>
 <button class="button1"  id="play"
 onclick="document.getElementById('sound1').play()">   
 Play</button>
```